# How would I translate words from a text file into piglatin

Tags: python, python-3.x

So through using 'for' statments I've broken down the textfile into lists as so:

```
['these', 'are', 'lines']
['meant', 'to', 'be', 'translated']
['to', 'piglatin']
```

So basically if it starts with a vowel 'aeiou' you take the word + 'yay' if it doesn't you move the letters to the back until you reach a vowel then add yay, and if it doesn't have a vowel you ignore it.

For example; about to be translated, would be: aboutyay otay ebay anslatedtray.

This is my code so far:

```
untranslated = open('english.txt','r')
vowels = 'aeiou'


for lines in untranslated:
    words = lines.split()
    print(words)
```

I don't want the full code on how to complete this just more or less how I would start with the first word and how to splice it.

Comment: Isn't pig-latin where you move the first letter to the end and add 'ay'?

Comment: My prof wants it as a different format then normal piglatin as it's an assignment. That's why I also don't want the full code.

Comment: Ah OK, check out my answer (on how to slice a string).

Answer (score 0):

How to slice a string:

```
word = 'these'
print word[0] # it's similar to list indexing, starts at 0
```

To get the letters in backwards order, use a negative number: `word[-1]` is the last letter; `word[-2]` is the second to last, etc.

`word[1:]` returns every letter from index 1 (the second letter) to the end.
'word[:5]`returns every letter up to index 5 (exclusive, letters 1, 2, 3, and 4).`
words[1:5]` returns every letter from index 1 up to index 5 (letters 2, 3, and 4).

Since you have multiple lines, you want to do `words += lines.split()` because

```
untranslated = open('english.txt','r')
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') # I like using lists/tuples rather than strings
# if you are just checking if something is in it
newWords = []

for lines in untranslated:
    words += lines.split() # this fixes the last line problem
    # this assumes each word is on one line, separated by a space (like: 'these are words')

for word in words: # iterates through every word
    if word[0] in vowels: # if first letter is a vowel
        new_word = word + 'yay'
    else:
        new_word = word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay'
        newWords.apend(new_word)
```

Based off of Eric Roper's suggestion, you can create a dictionary as a translation:

```
newWords = {}
for word in words:
    if word[0] in vowels:
        new_word = word + 'yay'
        newWords[word]  = new_word
    else:
        new_word = word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay'
        newWords[word] = new_word
```

Some references:

- [Strings](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm)
- [Dictionaries](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how I can translate word by word in a loop, I know in general how to splice a string though.

Comment: I think this is pretty much the full code, after a tweak.  A dictionary translation would be a nice touch IMO.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND For some reason it's only translating the last line of code.

Comment: @ajkey94 Check my edit; I changed it to `words += lines.split()`. This combines `words` and the words in the new line. Previously, it was `words = lines.split()` which will set `words` to every line, but not combine them. Therefore, it will be set to the last iteration.